# Re-arranging formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was asked to re-arrange the formula in terms of V for:

NI = (SP-VC)(V)-FC

These are the steps I have done and it was wrong. Can anyone explain

(1) NI/(SP-VC)=V-FC
(1) FC+[NI/(SP-VC)]

Comment: Try re-writing it in a form that might look more familiar:
$a=(b-c)x-d$; solve for $x$.

Comment: When you divide by SP-VC you must divide everything. You forgot to divide the final FC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}NI&=(SP-VC)\cdot V-FC\\
NI+FC&=(SP-VC)\cdot V\\
V&=\frac {NI+FC}{SP-VC}
\end{align}$$

(Does this have to do with Volume, Net Income, Fixed Cost, Selling Price and Variable Cost?)